# how to know powerpoint language with vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to know the language that powerpoint is using. I used to check it in ActivePresentation.DefaultLanguageID and it was working until now that I test it in a computer who puts that is in dutch but it is really working as it was an english one.

For example when saving the presentation as png, each slide is saved individually with Slide1.png name (in the english version) and in the dutch version is Dia1.png. It puts that the language is dutch but when I save the is as png I get Slide1.png instead of Dia1.png.

Is there any other way to check the langauge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following returns the user-interface language as a code number:

```
MsgBox Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
```

I'm in the UK and this returns 1033, even though this number is for the US. If you search (Microsoft or MSDN) you can find a list of these code numbers. A quick search [yields this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964664.aspx).

Comment: Just to add a bit, the PPT application can have a default language, each presentation can have its own default language that overrides the app default, each text frame can have its own language that overrides the presentation/app defaults.